Factor performance in different groups
While we are testing performances of factors, it is common for us to put stocks into different groups based on their exposure to certain factor, such as size, value, momentum,etc., Then we can test the performance of the trading strategy that buy/long the group of stocks with the largest exposure, or the strategy that short the group of stocks with the least amount of exposure. For example, we can have group 1 to group 5, group 1 have the largest exposure, and group 5 have the least amount of exposure. When we generate positive returns from buying group 1, does it necessarily means that we will also have positive returns by shorting group 5? I think for some factors this might be true, but it will not work for all factors. So, when a factor is effective in the case of buying/longing the group with the largest exposure, does it means that shorting the group with the least exposure can also make money? Thank you!

A similar question was asked here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/78673/fama-french-long-short-portfolios-is-short-really-necessary/78679#78679

Hi Gamma: Even defining the term "exposure" is difficult. Do you use a model like say barra for that ? If not, how do you get the exposures ?


When we generate positive returns from buying group 1, does it necessarily means that we will also have positive returns by shorting group 5?

No. This is because, it is (almost always) the case where group 1 performs better than group 5, which means that when group 1 has a large positive return, group 5 can either have a smaller positive or negative return.
The former which contradicts your case as a smaller positive return results in a loss in your short.
The whole idea behind a long (short) top (bottom) deciles is just to earn the spread in returns between the two groups, which reflects the factor returns.

There's no general answer to this question; you have to test each factor. Sometimes shorting group 5 will be profitable, but often it won't be, due to the long-term upward tendency of stocks.
The best library in Python for analyzing factors is Alphalens. You can see example analyses of a variety of different factors on QuantRocket's blog.
